# CMake project compilation error on VisualStudio using external SDK toolchain file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sdk, cross-compiling

I am using **VisualStudio** **CMake project** on **Windows** machine.

I am using an external **SDK** in order to **cross compile** my **C++** program for **Linux arm architecture**.

I added the SDK toolchain to cmakeToolchain path which is :

*/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake*

and this is my **CMakeLists.txt** file :

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
#list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/ubuntu/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/boost/usr/include/boost)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include)
Set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
#set(BOOST_ROOT "/home/ubuntu/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/boost")

message(STATUS "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}'")
set(CROSS_COMPILER_DIR /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER_DIR}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER_DIR}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER='${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}'")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}'")

find_package(Boost 1.66.0) 

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message (STATUS "success!")
    add_executable (CMakeProject4 "CMakeProject4.cpp" "CMakeProject4.h") 
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})  
    target_link_libraries(CMakeProject4 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

endif()
```

As you can see I am setting my SDK compilers bin paths to **CMAKE_C_COMPILER** and **CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER** variables.

When I Debug, I find that :

```
1> Copying files to the remote machine.
1> Starting copying files to remote machine.
1> [rsync] rsync -t --delete --delete-excluded -v -r --exclude=.vs --exclude=.git --exclude=out  "." rsync://ubuntu@localhost:56934/-home-ubuntu-CMake-RemoteCML
1> [rsync] sending incremental file list
1> [rsync] 
1> [rsync] sent 229 bytes  received 13 bytes  161.33 bytes/sec
1> [rsync] total size is 4,429  speedup is 18.30
1> Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:04s:043ms).
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'Linux-Release'.
1> Found cmake executable at /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake.
1> /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="RelWithDebInfo" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_LIBRARIES:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteIL "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteCML/CMakeLists.txt";
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- broken
1> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
1> [CMake]   The C++ compiler
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     "/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   It fails with the following output:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_2cb5a/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/build
1> [CMake]     make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
1> [CMake]     Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
1> [CMake]     Linking CXX executable cmTC_2cb5a
1> [CMake]     /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_2cb5a 
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
1> [CMake]     /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
1> [CMake]     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
1> [CMake]     CMakeFiles/cmTC_2cb5a.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'cmTC_2cb5a' failed
1> [CMake]     make[1]: *** [cmTC_2cb5a] Error 1
1> [CMake]     make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
1> [CMake]     Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_2cb5a/fast' failed
1> [CMake]     make: *** [cmTC_2cb5a/fast] Error 2
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> [CMake] See also "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
1> cd "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR";/home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="RelWithDebInfo" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_LIBRARIES:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteIL "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteCML" 2>&1; returned with exit code: 1
```

I can see here that CMake can identify the SDK toolchain compiler which I want to use which is GNU 7.3.0 but it's broken!
 When I open **CMakeCache.txt** , I find this :

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:UNINITIALIZED=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7

CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:UNINITIALIZED=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake
```

This is my C++ .cpp file program :

```
#include "CMakeProject4.h"
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::cout << "Type in any number: ";

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout
        << (boost::lambda::_1 * 10)
        << "\nType in another number: ");
}
```

But when I try to run CMake in order to compile my program using :

```
cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

I have this error :

[Error Compilation](https://pastebin.com/jLpMe0eP)

Any help please ?

Comment: I think the toolchain file is not being used. Why on the cache it say uninitialized? Did you edit the cache by hand or used the toolchain file argument?

Comment: On VisualStudio I just go to Project -> Generate Cach for CMake project

Answer (score 1):

When you use a toolchain file, you shouldn't set the compiler yourself. You should let it to the toolchain file, as it know how to cross compile. Things like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` should be left to the toolchain file.

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

# I think the prefix should point to usr directly, not the include directory
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}'")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER='${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}'")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}'")

project(whatever CXX)

# Better to fail fast when there's a package missing
find_package(Boost 1.66.0 REQUIRED) 

add_executable (CMakeProject4 CMakeProject4.cpp CMakeProject4.h) 
target_link_libraries(CMakeProject4 PRIVATE Boost::headers)
```

And your CMake arguments should look like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake
```

Comment: when I did not set the compiler myself, and when I edited my project as yours response, now, I can find that the compiler used is the default one. In `CMakeCache` file I find `CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++`

Comment: The toolchain file should set the compiler properly for cross compilation. This is how a well formed CMake project should operate. Is the toochain file exist and has content at the path you sent? And if the toolchain file don't setup the cross compiling environment as it should, edit the file or report the but to your distribution.

Comment: This toolchain file path which I put here has only the OEToolchainConfig.cmake file in the directory. When I use this toolchain my Linux distribution ( where I build it ) I setup the environment manualy whenever I use it. Now if this is the problem how can I setup the environment on VisualStudio on Windows ?

Comment: If you run CMake on your windows machine, CMake must be able to find the file somehow. I assume you run on WSL? I'm not a windows expert, but when cross compiling you usually run a toolchain (compiler, build system, etc.) on a host machine to compile a project on a target machine. If you run on linux on a virtual machine and try to cross compile to ARM for an embedded sytem, then your host should be linux, unless WSL let you run linux program on a windows environment.

Comment: Well I am not using WSL project. Furthermore, I have succeded to compile a program on VS on my windows machine and run it on Linux machine ( intel x64 arch) but not using the SDK. I think the problem in the SDK environment setup. Did you see my edit to the Debug message saying that the compiler is broken ?

Comment: @Gonn I would suggest to open the command line (you can open a terminal inside vscode) and try to type `cat /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake`. If your command cannot find that file, your CMake won't either. I would also suggest to try your compiler directly on the VSCode command line too, to see if you have access to your compiler. If both succeed, I would use CMake to check if the toolchain file and the compiler exist with `if(EXISTS "file")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208197/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-gonn).